# How to deploy a Manipulate object to the cloud that enables SynchronousUpdating?

Tags: deployment

Is it possible to deploy a Manipulate object in the cloud that enables the SynchronousUpdating, which response immediately ?

For example, to make something like this in one of the Wolfram's [blog](http://blog.stephenwolfram.com/2013/04/data-science-of-the-facebook-world/)

[image]

Comment: I believe that was pre-generated.  Are you interested in pre-generating all the frames, or only in live computations?

Comment: @Szabolcs I guess I'm interested in both, as long as there is no waiting time between results.